# import java.util.Scanner not working with codenameone

Tags: java, codenameone

I try looking online for solution, but couldn't find one. It my first time using codenameone , why does import java.util.Scanner doesn't work with codenameone project in eclipse?
I know the JAVA_HOME path is good and everything is updated.

WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.

Comment: Does HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Prefs exist on your machine? You can check that by using regedit

Comment: In addition to that, `Scanner` is a bit problematic as it has a lot of regex dependencies which are hard to get right into the VM in a way that is 100% cross platform so you would end up with `Scanner` working in one way on one OS and another way on another OS. We have a regex library and parsers for various file formats (CSV, XML, Properties) so if you have a specific use case for `Scanner` I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue with a freshly installed Java on windows, you can solve this by doing the following:

1. Go to your Start Menu and type `regedit` into the search field.
2. Navigate to path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft` (Windows 10 seems to now have this here: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node\JavaSoft)`
3. Right click on the JavaSoft folder and click on `New` -> `Key`
4. Name the new Key `Prefs` and everything should work.

Alternatively, create a new file named `java.reg` with the following content and execute it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs]
```